# Compiler Error : An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, compiler-errors, expression-trees

Consider the following code, which wraps *(rather than using inheritance for specific reasons)* an instance of `Dictionary<string, T>` and implements `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` so that it can be used with linq queries:

```
public class LinqTest<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>, IQueryable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>
{
    private Dictionary<string, T> items = default(Dictionary<string, T>);

    public virtual T this[string key]
    {
        get { return this.items.ContainsKey(key) ? this.items[key] : default(T); }
        set { this.items[key] = value; }
    }

    public virtual T this[int index]
    {
        get { return this[index.ToString()]; }
        set { this[index.ToString()] = value; }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return this.items.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return this.items.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return this.items.AsQueryable().Provider; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I tested this code as follows:

```
LinqTest<dynamic> item = new LinqTest<dynamic>();
item["a"] = 45;
item["b"] = Guid.NewGuid();
item["c"] = "Hello World";
item["d"] = true;

item.Where(o => o.Value.GetType() == typeof(Guid)).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

//Compiler error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

This indicates to me that `o.Value.GetType() == typeof(Guid)` cannot be compiled into the expression because it is `dynamic`.

However, I tested this theory with the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> item = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
item["a"] = 45;
item["b"] = Guid.NewGuid();
item["c"] = "Hello World";
item["d"] = true;

item.Where(o => o.Value.GetType() == typeof(Guid)).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

This compiles, and runs without ANY errors, and contains a dynamic expression...can anyone explain, and possibly point out how I can fix my code?

**Note:** `.ForEach` is a non-standard extension method which implements a foreach loop.

Comment: Do you use this with Linq to Sql?  Or just Linq to Objects?

Comment: @Will, just Linq to Objects (for the time being)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your type implements `IQueryable<>`, so the `Queryable` method is chosen by member lookup - so the compiler tries to create an expression tree from your lambda expression... and that's what fails.

The dictionary example succeeds because it's using `Enumerable` rather than `Queryable`, so it's converting the lambda expression into a delegate instead.

You can fix your code by using `AsEnumerable`:

```
item.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(o => o.Value.GetType() == typeof(Guid))
    .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

It's not clear why you're implementing `IQueryable<>` at all, to be honest - another simpler option would simply be to stop doing that. Your source data is just a `Dictionary`, so that's already going to be using LINQ to Objects instead of anything queryable-based... why introduce `IQueryable<>` at all?

Comment: "Why introduce IQueryable<> at all" - because I was foolish enough to not research the (massive and absolute) differences between IEnumerable and IQueryable, and believed in my ignorance that LINQ extensions were only available on objects implementing IQueryable<>. Thanks very much for your answer! :-)